# How to build a stateful Webpack loader?

Tags: javascript, webpack, gleam

I am trying to build a Webpack loader for [Gleam language](https://gleam.run/) that compiles to JavaScript. Since, gleam has a standalone compiler and compilation unit is entire package as opposed to file-based system of Webpack, I need to maintain **the state** to avoid the repetitive compilation of the **gleam** source code.

But, Webpack [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-loader/#stateless) recommends that loaders should be [stateless](https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-loader/#stateless). Without maintaining the state, it is impossible to keep track of mapping of compiled files and their source gleam files. I also did not find any such documentation about this on Webpack docs.

So, how can I achieve this? Is there some other Webpack process-level API that can be utilized to achieve this?

Comment: I wonder why the question has a close vote. It is focused and exactly asks for one thing.